What will be the trajectory of a point on a rigid body in the case of rolling with slipping?
In the case of pure rolling (of say, a cylinder), the trajectory of any point on its rim will be a cycloid. More generally, the trajectory of any point on the body will be a trochoid. How does this change as the body slips while rolling (transrotational motion)?

What do you mean by "impure rolling"?

Yes @VincentThacker,

Parametric equations of trochoid are:
\begin{equation}
x = A\theta-B \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y = A-B \sin(\theta),
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the body radius and $B$ the distance between the rigid point on the body and the center of the body.
To implement slip, you need a slip factor, that is the number of times the body spins over itself when traveling a distance $2\pi A$; let's name this factor $S$. So parametric equations are now:
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{A\theta}{S}-B \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y = A-B \sin(\theta),
\end{equation}
where you can recover the expresion of the trochoid with $S=1$ (the value of no slipping). Also if $S=\infty$, which corresponds with total slipping, just a body rotating over itself, you extract the correct solution of $x$ not moving on time.

Thanks a lot for your efforts and also thanks for increasing the radius of my knowledge!
